# Type bytes32[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes32 [] storage pointer

Tags: solidity

I am receiving, the error below:

`Type bytes32[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes32[] storage pointer.`

when unpacking what should be a `bytes32` i.e. `a` in `Problem` struct (1).

```
//FileOne.sol
contract ExampleOne {

  struct Problem {
    bytes32 a; // (1)
    bytes32 b;
    bytes32[] c;
    uint d;
    }
  mapping (bytes32 => Problem) public problems;
}

//FileTwo.sol
contract IExampleOne {
  function problems(bytes32) public returns (bytes32, bytes32, bytes32[], uint);
  }

contract Example Two {

  IExampleOne exampleOne;

  constructor(address _exampleOne) {
    exampleOne = IExampleOne(_exampleOne);
  }

  function func(bytes32 name) {
    (bytes32 a, bytes32 b, bytes32[] c, uint d) = problems(name); //ERROR
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Your coding is not so easy to read. Why do you use the same name for different objects in different files? May be it could better rewrite it in a more readable manner and reopen the question. Anyway, generally speaking, a cast can solve the formal problem, but who can say that it results in what you expect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news. It compiles with a few tweaks.

Bad news. This is hard on gas and depending on the length of the arrays being passed around it may be too expensive to be practical - standard caution whenever arrays are involved in the interface.

As an alternative, you could create getters for the scalar values (`return (p.a, p.b, p.d)`) and individual rows in the array (`return p.c[row];`). Doing so will ensure the individual invocations will cost the same and conserve gas.

For your code to compile, the trick is to cast `c[]` as a `memory` pointer. That corresponds to the data received from the other contract via the ABI (i.e. not from storage). By default, it was a storage pointer.

```
//FileOne.sol
contract ExampleOne {

  struct Problem {
    bytes32 a; // (1)
    bytes32 b;
    bytes32[] c;
    uint d;
    }
  mapping (bytes32 => Problem) public problems;
}

//FileTwo.sol
contract IExampleOne {
  function problems(bytes32) public returns (bytes32, bytes32, bytes32[], uint);
  }

contract ExampleTwo {

  IExampleOne exampleOne;

  constructor(address _exampleOne) {
    exampleOne = IExampleOne(_exampleOne);
  }

  function func(bytes32 name) {
    (bytes32 a, bytes32 b, bytes32[] memory c, uint d) = exampleOne.problems(name); // NO ERROR
    //...
  }
}
```

In case the comments about scalability are of interest, the concern is it will take increasing amounts of gas on both sides to pack and unpack larger and larger lists. Your `ExampleOne` can offer the potential to read it at any scale using many tiny calls instead of one big one.

```
function getProblemMeta(bytes32 problemId) public view returns(bytes32, bytes32, uint) {
  p = problems[problemId];
  return (p.a, p.b, p.d);
}

function getProblemCAtIndex(bytes32 problemId, uint index) public view returns(bytes32) {
  return problems[problemId].c[index];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for this thorough answer. Casting to `memory` solves this issue I was having. Scalability is definitely of interest, glad you noticed my current implementation is poor in that regard. I'll try to incorporate those smaller calls where I can!